# что не работает в htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /


    # тут хочу делать перенаправление для разных поддоменов на свой robots файл.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+).mysite.ru [NC]
    RewriteRule ^robots\.txt /robots_%1.txt [NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Нужно, что бы для каждого поддемена свой robots файл подружался. В чем ошибка? не работае, а ошибок нет.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/599395/186083